# comparing 2 json effectively

Tags: java, json

I have a json lets say json 1

```
[
    {
        "id": "123",
        "testname": "test123",
        "name": "John Doe",
        "active": true,
        "type": "test6"
    }

 {
        "id": "456",
        "testname": "test564",
        "name": "Ship Therasus",
        "active": true,
        "type": "test7"
    }

.... some 100 entries 
]
```

and json 2 some like below

```
[
    {
        "id": "123",
        "country": "USA",
        "state": "KA",
        "age": 24,
        "group": "g1"
    }

 {
        "id": "456",
        "country": "UK",
        "state": "MA",
        "age": 28,
        "group": "G2"
    }

...... 100 entries
]
```

Now Id is the constant thing between json1 and json2  I want to make a resultant json something like below lets call json3.I want to match the id and  get country and  state from json2 and append to  json 1.I am not looking for code but if i do brute force it takes 100* 100 and hence performance issues. is there any better way to handle this in less complexity?

```
[
    {
        "id": "123",
        "testname": "test123",
        "name": "John Doe",
        "active": true,
        "type": "test6",
        "country":"USA",
         "state":"KA"
    }

 {
        "id": "456",
        "testname": "test564",
        "name": "Ship Therasus",
        "active": true,
        "type": "test7",
         "country":"UK",
         "state":"MA"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

The best approach to this problem is O(size(json1 || json2)), because inherently you will have to go through atleast one of the json lists fully to loop through all of the IDs. If you have a constant time lookup (like a hashmap, keyed by the ID), you will be able to pull the information about that specific ID. Honestly I'm not familiar enough with json to suggest a data structure to use, but I know in Java, hashmaps are a frequently used constant time lookup. The best approach would be:

- Loop through one json list
- Pull out the ID from each entry in this list
- Look up the information from the other json list using the same ID
- Combine all the information in a resulting json list

Although this answer is somewhat vague, I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Without making any assumptions, I can't think of any way to avoid the O(n^2) complexity based on the given information.

However, if your arrays were already sorted by the object id, you could speed it up by iterating over the array.

```
var json3 = [];

for(var i = 0; i < json1.length; i++) {
    json3.push($.extend({}, json1[i], json2[i]));
}
```

If you have control over the data structure, an object that is keyed by the id would be much easier to work with than an array:
e.g.

```
json1 = {
"123": {"testname": "test123", ...},"456": {...}
}
```

Then your code would simply

```
var json3 = {};
for(var id in json1) {
    json3[id] = $.extend({}, json1[id], json2[id]));
}
```